# Panel layouts splits wrong

Tags: java, layout, jpanel, frame

I want to split my program [like this](http://prntscr.com/85qfw4).
I tried to add another panel (yellow one) but its just goes on top of a panel.
I know that for some reason the left panel is all over the left side and not just the red area.

```
public class Panel {

  private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("World Editor v0.1");;
  private static JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  private static JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
  private static JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
  private static Canvas glCanvas = new Canvas();
  private static JMenuBar mb = new JMenuBar();
  private static Loader loader;
  private static Renderer renderer;
  private static File f = new File("Entites.txt");

  public static void gui() {
    panel2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Settings"));  
    panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
    panel2.setBackground(Color.GRAY);

    panel3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Top Panel"));  
    panel3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1));
    panel3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);


    frame.add(panel2);
    frame.add(panel3);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(1280, 1024);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    panel.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    gui();
    setCanvas();
    DisplayManager.createDisplay();
    loader = new Loader();
    renderer = new Renderer();

    float[] vertices =
    { -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0f, 0.5f, -0.5f, 0f,

    0.5f, -0.5f, 0f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0f, -0.5f, 0.5f, 0f };

    RawModel model = loader.loadToVAO(vertices);

    while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
        renderer.prepare();
        renderer.render(model);
        DisplayManager.updateDisplay();
    }

    DisplayManager.closeDisplay();
  }


  private static void setCanvas() {
    glCanvas.setIgnoreRepaint(true);
    glCanvas.setSize(720, 480);
    panel.add(glCanvas, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    try {
        Display.setParent(glCanvas);
    } catch (LWJGLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should not mix Swing components with AWT components (like Canvas).

Comment: so how can i create that type of screen like i want ?